# TypeError: store.get is not a function - NestJs, cache-manager

Tags: nestjs

I'm implementing caching following the [NestJS docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching).

Create new project for this so there's no difference between docs example and this.

1. imports CacheModule.. just like docs

```
import { CacheModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [CacheModule.register()],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

2. Inject CacheManager..

```
import { CACHE_MANAGER, Controller, Get, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache,
  ) {}
}
```

3. And use it

```
  @Get()
  async getHello(): Promise<string> {
    const value: string = await this.cacheManager.get('hello');
    if (value === null) {
      await this.cacheManager.set('hello', 'cache item', 60);
      return 'no cache exists';
    }
    return value;
  }
```

but I get this error, I don't know why:

```
TypeError: store.get is not a function
    at Object.get (.../node_modules/cache-manager/src/caching.ts:88:36)
    at AppController.getHello
```

This is a simple job, I think.

So there's no one seems to get this error (I looked it up).

Answer (score 20):

I came across the same error and could not figure it out either.

**node-cache-manager** was only updated to version 5 within the last day.
https://github.com/node-cache-manager/node-cache-manager/tags

So I updated the `package.json` to use version 4.x

```
"cache-manager": "^4.0.0",
```

And now the caching works as expected.

Keep an eye on the package issue queue for further updates.

Comment: To add onto this, the upgrade to v5 was a breaking change, and discussion about this specifically can be seen in [this issue](https://github.com/node-cache-manager/node-cache-manager/issues/210)

Comment: You save my day then after 5 hours :), thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`package.json`

```json
"dependencies": {
  "cache-manager": "^4.1.0",
  "cache-manager-redis-store": "^2.0.0"
}
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/cache-manager": "^4.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps to get it working on v5

1. Upgrade `@nestjs/core`, `@nestjs/common` and `@nestjs/cli` to use > `9.4.0`
2. install `@nesjs/cache-manager` package
3. in your `app.ts`

```
import { CacheModule } from '@nestjs/cache-manager'; // not from "cache-manager"
```

4. add this

```
        CacheModule.register({
            isGlobal: true,
// if you use redis
            useFactory: async () => ({
                store: redisStore as any,
                host: config.REDIS_HOST,
                port: config.REDIS_PORT,
                // ttl: 1000,
            }),
        }),
```

**NOTE**: Don't use `CacheModule.resgisterAsync`

Run Your app and it should work fine

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue last year and couldn't find a proper solution. In the end, I had to resort to downgrading to a previous version, as mentioned in some of the previous answers. However, today I faced the same problem again and after couple of hours...

for newer versions of cache-manager, this should work:

*NB: the example demonstrate a custom nestjs cache service to make caching implementation agnostic*

**For version > 5.0.0.**

```js
// cache.module.ts
import { redisStore } from "cache-manager-redis-store";
import { CacheService } from "./cache.service";
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { CacheModule as CacheModule_ } from "@nestjs/cache-manager";
import ...

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule_.registerAsync({
      isGlobal: true,
      inject: [
        ConfigService
      ],
      useFactory: async (configs: ConfigService) => ({
        isGlobal: true,
        max: 10_000,
        store: (): any => redisStore({
          commandsQueueMaxLength: 10_000,
          socket: {
            host: configs.getOrThrow("REDIS_HOST"),
            port: configs.getOrThrow("REDIS_PORT"),
          }
        })
      })
    })
  ],
  exports: [CacheService],
  providers: [CacheService],
})
export class CacheModule { }


// cache.service.ts
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';
import { RedisStore } from "cache-manager-redis-store";
import { CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable({})
export class CacheService {
  constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private readonly cache: Cache & RedisStore) { }

  async get<T = unknown>(key: string) {
    return this.cache.get<T>(key);
  }

  async set(key: string, value: any, seconds = 600 /* 10min */) {
    return this.cache.set(key, value, { ttl: seconds }, null);
  }

  async del(key: string) {
    return this.cache.del(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue. They have recently upgraded to a newer version. Take a look at the new docs[doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cache-manager)